# Standalone return expression explanation

Tags: android

I was online looking at some  android coding examples and i came across a method that had a return expression by itself,and i was wondering if someone could explain what that means.

Here is the code sample:

```
if(tempText.getText().length() ==0){

    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

     return;
 }
```

Comment: in if condition you are checking the length of variable. If it is "0" then you are showing toast to enter a valid number.

Comment: Just means to leave the method at this point. The method must be declared with `void` return type.

Answer (score 1):

This is the `If` condition which checks for the length of the text which is "0" or not. If its "0" then it will show the `Toast` message and will return from or exit from the if loop an no further execution will processed.

Comment: "if loop" ... makes my toe nails curl

Answer (score 1):

using **if** condition you are checking for the length of text, if it is **0** then you are showing **Toast**

Using a **return Keyword** within a class, with a method

*A method returning nothing*

```
public void Void_Method()

{

<statements>

return;

}
```

*A method returning a String*

```
public String String_Method()

{

String s = "its Ridiculous to do such kind of work, people here are just aim less";

return s;

}
```

*A method returning an Int value*

```
public int Int_Method()

{

int i = 5;

return(i);

}
```

I hope this will help you understand the use of ***return keyword***, and as name suggest - **The return keyword is always used with a method only to specify that the method is going to return something.**